# Silveright Business App Samples. Need some good references

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, business-application

I am working on a SL4 RIA Business application and would like to get all the reference code out on the web I can find.. from a book is fine too..  Anyone know a few good ones?  I will search the web but wanted to ask here as well incase I miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of reference apps/samples -

http://riaservices.codeplex.com/